# Can I show that $n \cdot \binom{n-1}{n}=0$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

**A brief question**: I know that $\binom{n}{k}$ isn't defined for $n<k$, however, can I show that $n\cdot \binom{n-1}{n}=0$? if so how can I do that? I saw through wolfram that it really is zero, and I was wondering how he got into it. I have encountered this debate in a question when I needed to find a closed form of the next series: $$\sum _{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}( n-k)$$

And instead of getting $n$ out first, I have tried to do the following steps: $$\sum _{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}( n-k) =\sum _{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{k!( n-k) !}( n-k) =\sum _{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{k!( n-k-1) !}\\
\\
=n\sum _{k=0}^{n}\frac{( n-1) !}{k!( n-k-1) !} =n\sum _{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k} =n\left[\binom{n-1}{n} +\underbrace{\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}}_{ \begin{array}{l}
\text{by Newton's binomial}\ \\
\text{it is }2^{n-1}
\end{array}}\right]\\
=n\left[\binom{n-1}{n} +2^{n-1}\right] =n\binom{n-1}{n} +n2^{n-1}$$

Now is it valid to right this as final result of a closed form for $\sum _{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}( n-k)$?

---

I will be happy to see from you if both questions I wrote are correct, and why.

Comment: It all depends on your preferred definitions. If you define $n\choose k$ (for all natural numbers [incl 0] $n,k$) as the number of ways of choosing a subset of size $k$ from a given set of size $n$ then you have no problems.

Comment: ... or if you define ${n \choose k}$ as $\frac{n\times (n-1) \times \cdots \times (n-k+1)}{k!}$ for non-negative integer $k$ and real $n$ then you also have no problems as you are multiplying by $(n-1)-n+1=0$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$n\choose k$ is equal to $0$ for $n<k$, so your expression simplifies to $$n\cdot 0$$ which is obviously equal to $0$.

---

The fact that $${n\choose k} = 0$$ for $n<k$ comes down to the definition of $n\choose k$. The value is defined as

> The number of $k$-element subsets of a $n$-element set.

From this definition, the fact should be fairly obvious, since if $k>n$, there are **no** subsets of an $n$-element set that contain *more* than $n$ elements.

Comment: So you are saying that is well defined to be zero for $n<k$, so it isn't a mistake writing it as a final result for a question. Right?

Comment: @dfdf1 Correct, it is well defined, and it is zero. So you can write it no problem, just know it is $0$.

Comment: thank you so much!!! By the way, the question that led me to write it here, is related to choosing subsets :) 
So it is make sense.

Comment: As a side note,  this is the same reason why $0!=1$, because $n!$ counts the number of permutations of $n$ objects, and there's exactly one permutation of nothing.  A set theorist will also say $0^0=1$ as it counts the number of functions from the empty set to the empty set,  which is 1, the empty function.   Analysists may disagree with that point though! @dfdf1